# Python Iterating over variables

Tags: python, loops

I want to write a for loop that iterates over variables and updates their values. 
for example:

```
x = 1
y = 1
for varNames in [x,y]:
    varNames = varNames + 1
print(x)
print(y)
```

Here I want to have the function print the value 2 for both x and y, but my output is still 1. It is because the varNames variable gets updated but not x and y. How do I update the values for actual variable names x and y?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can't iterate over *variables*, you iterate over *containers* / *iterables*. It seems like all your objects should be in a list, then you could loop over and modify your list.

Comment: You want a dictionary.

Comment: @jfaccioni or *some kind of container* depending on the exact use case.

Comment: `x=1;y=2` and unpack them `x,y=[i+1 for i in [x,y]]` should work.

Comment: This works, Thanks very much @Ch3steR!

Comment: @user5977110 Use pythontutor to visualize whats happening it helps you understand well. http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display

Answer (score 4):

At the global level (i.e. not within a function) you could do this using the globals() function.

```
x = 1
y = 1
for varName in ["x","y"]:
    globals()[varName] += 1
print(x) # 2
print(y) # 2
```

However, if you need to do that kind of thing in your program, you might want to learn more about lists and dictionaries which would be the preferred approach.

```
data = dict()
data["x"] = 1
data["y"] = 1
for varName in data:
    data[varName] = data[varName] + 1
print(data["x"]) # 2
print(data["y"]) # 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just make a list containing the variables and then you can iterate over them and print each object of the list.

```
x = 1 
y = 3
mylist=[x,y]
for index in mylist:
    print(index)
```

Comment: this doesn't answer OP's question. they want to update the values of `x` and `y`, not the values within `mylist`.

Comment: @wpercy yeah, but this is really what the OP needs. You don't always need what you want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `x,y=[i+1 for i in[x,y]]` works but is it recommended?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I disagree. I understand the concept of an XY problem, but I don't think that this is doing remotely what the OP is asking, it's simply printing values in the list? IIUC OP just wants a dictionary

Comment: @Ch3steR no, that is absurd, you would just do `x, y = x + 1, y + 1`. If it ever got to the point where that would be unweildy then its screaming at you **use a container like a list or a dict**

Comment: @wpercy what the OP is asking for *doesn't make sense*. It isn't the way to do things. If the OP wants to manipulate a bunch of objects together, then the OP should put those objects *in a list or some other appropriate container*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't disagree, I think that OP does just want a dictionary here, but I still don't see how this answer is remotely appropriate for the question. there's no modification of the values in the list, it's literally just printing the values...

Comment: @wpercy May be he intended to tell that *this answer doesn't make any sense so does the question*.

Comment: @Ch3steR sure, I'm mostly disagreeing with `"but this is really what the OP needs"` this isn't remotely what they need.